# Export from PHP Interesting error

Tags: php, mysql, excel

An error in this code, for exporting it to excel. If not use line 1 and 2 code is working perfectly. If use line 1 and line 2 code it's working but `don't export  to excel`, redirect to PHP control page. Also can see result there its normal. Where is the problem?

```
    $servis_listesi = mysql_query("SELECT * from servis_listesi");


    while($tumservisler = mysql_fetch_array($servis_listesi)){

    $ad_servis = $tumservisler["servis_adi"];
    $kod_servis = $tumservisler["servis_kodu"];
    $servisil = $tumservisler["servis_il"];  // line 1 
    $servisilce = $tumservisler["servis_ilce"];  // line 2

    $ortalamasi = mysql_query("select avg(anket_puani),COUNT(anket_puani) from anket_sonuclar where servis_kodu='".$kod_servis."' and anket_tarihi between '".$tarih1."' and '".$tarih2."'");
    $bicimle = mysql_fetch_array($ortalamasi);


    $sonuc_reel = $bicimle["avg(anket_puani)"];
    $sonuc_sayi = $bicimle["COUNT(anket_puani)"];

    $sonuc_net = round($sonuc_reel,2);


        echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$kod_servis.'</td>
                    <td>'.$ad_servis.'</td>
                    <td>'.$servisil.'</td> <!-- line 1 want to use here-->
                    <td>'.$servisilce.'</td><!-- line 2 want to use here-->
                    <td>'.$sonuc_sayi.'</td> 
                    <th></th>
                    <td>'.$sonuc_net.'</td>


        </tr>';




    };
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename='anket_list ".date('d.m.Y').".xls");
```

Comment: Interesting Title, Boring question :-/

Comment: is there `servis_il` , `servis_ilce` fields in `teknisyen_listesi` table?

Comment: $servis_listesi = mysql_query("SELECT * from servis_listesi");

I shared wrong line. This is true line. Yes include servis_il and servis_ilce field servis_listesi.

Comment: Is there any code to generate excel file ?

Comment: It could very well be that your PHP version doesn't allow the use of `mysql_*` functions anymore, you should move over to PDO or `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename='anket_list ".date('d.m.Y').".xls");

Comment: I will try and share result with mysqli. But not solved yet i think.

Comment: 1) try to remove the `<th></th>` line 2) to repeat comment from @mith: have you double-checked, that the columns `servis_il` and `servis_ilce` exist in your table `teknisyen_listesi`?

Comment: My problem isnt with mysql . Doesn't export to excel if i use line 1 and line 2. it is redirect to my php control page and result is perfect. but i am needing export to excel. If use not line 1 and line 2 exported to excel.

Comment: also checked servis_il and servis_ilce another table dont use it here. i am using servis_il , servis_ilce use in servis_listesi mysql_table.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mahir if it is possible please try the give code below and check once.
$tumservisler = mysql_fetch_array($servis_listesi);
while($tumservisler){

}

Comment: Hi Ram neduri. Thank you but dont working redirect to control page again and the while is not stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Error is solved. I used the previous `header`s that is all. Thanks.